# single page application with angularjs and facebook share button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I follow this post to deploy facebook share botton in my app
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to-your-web-site-pages/

The first problem is I can not pass `post.id`, `post.caption` to facebook script.

The second one is the link to every post on facebook wall `link: ' link to every {{post.id}}'`. If people click on a link shared on their wall, it should jum (AUTO SCROLL) to specific post on my site, this is single page so all post have the same link

Thanks so much!

This is my Angularjs controller:

```
function MyController($scope) {
            $scope.posts = [{"title": "AAtitle",
                            "content":"AAcontent",
                            "caption":"AAcaption",
                            "id":"adfddsf"dfsdfdsds
                           },
                           {"title": "BBtitle",
                            "content":"BBcontent",
                            "caption":"BBcaption",
                            "id":"dfgfddrggdgdgdgfd"
                           },
                            {"title": "CCtitle",
                            "content":"CCcontent",
                            "caption":"CCcaption",
                            "id":"dhgfetyhnncvcbcqqq"
                           }
                          ]
        }
```

This is facebook SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'MY APP ID', status: true, cookie: true,
xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

This is my html

```
<div ng-controller = "MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "post in posts">
           <div> {{post.title}} </div>
           <div> {{post.content}} </div>
           <div> <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#{{post.id}}').click(function(e){    //unrecognized expression: {{post.id}}
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui(
                {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
                link: ' link to every {{post.id}}',
                caption: '{{post.caption'}},
                });
                });
                });
                </script>
                <div id = "{{post.id}}">share </div>
        </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I used this page to create a facebook like button on an angular app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Comment: @rob I have tried it before, but it had not worked as my expectation

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you could register share button click event handler in "Angular way". Move the logic to controller and use ng-click directive to trigger share action.

My implementation

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="fbCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div>{{post.title}}</div>
        <div>{{post.content}}</div>
        <button ng-click="share(post)">SHARE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("fbCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.posts = [{id:1,title:"title1",content:"content1",caption:"caption1"},{id:2,title:"title2",content:"content2",caption:"caption2"}];
  $scope.share = function(post){
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
        link: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/'+post.id,
        picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/share-image.gif',
        caption: post.caption,
        description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
        message: ''
    });
  }
});
```

Screenshot

[image]

You could create a service for FACEBOOK sharing if this function will apply to multiple parts.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yeah! It's work, This is very helpful. This help to solve my first problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: I keep getting this message. "An error occurred. Please try later". Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: i have this error "API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

Comment: @Jocker Well ... Error 191 is a Facebook API integration issue. You should check your site URL setting (redirect_url should be equal or relative to the site URL). And I think it's not an Angular related issue : )

Answer (score 6):

Here's also a directive built based on Chickenrice's answer.

**Html:**

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>


  <button fb-share>
      <img src="/assets/images/icons/icon-fb.png">
  </button>

</body>
```

**Directive:**

```
'use strict';
/* global FB */

myApp.directive('fbShare', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: 'Name you want to show',
                        link: 'http://link-you-want-to-show',
                        picture: 'http://picture-you-want-to-show',
                        caption: 'Caption you want to show',
                        description: 'Description you want to show',
                        message: 'Message you want to show'
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

If you use jshint (you should) the `/* global FB */` part is there in so you don't get undefined variable warning.