# Facebook Share Dialog Issue

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

So this is probably a simple problem I'm not seeing but here goes.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: $location.absUrl(),
}, function(response){});
```

this makes the popup come out and everything, however, after I click post and check my facebook wall. Nothing is actually posted.

What could be the issue?

Comment: maybe console.log your response to see what is says?

Comment: nothing it is a blank array []

Comment: looks like this guy has done it right with ng: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533846/single-page-application-with-angularjs-and-facebook-share-button

Comment: mmmm, i don't think this should be the issue...