# single page application with angularjs and google+ button

Tags: angularjs, google-plus, single-page-application

I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537386/744040 solution to define the content of the Facebook sharing window.

I can't find a similar solution for Google +.

I am working on this website http://sportnews.codeskeleton.com/ and if you go to an article page and try to G+, it'll take a wrong image as thumbnail and for the title it takes the AngularJS code : Sportnew7-24 - <% Page.title() %> (I use <% instead of {{ to avoid collision with blade ).

I tried the solution with schema.org but the google popin seems to ignore them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google+ share details are populated by Google making an HTTP request to the specified URL and parsing the HTML. Since you are making a SPA site Google is just parsing the default template details without executing your JavaScript. If you want Google+ sharing details to work you will have to render the HTML with the title/image in it.

Google does have a [method](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) for telling crawlers about AJAX pages and how to crawl them but I can't speak to if the Google+ bot supports the standard.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to let go the SPA for standard pages. SPA are so common nowadays that I think there may be a workaround for this.

Comment: I've added a link to how Google Search supports SPAs. It still requires rendering content server side though. SPAs are frequently apps for interactivity and not so much content for crawling.