# Google Plus Share Using Angularjs and Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to prerender a page in angular which happens to have a dynamic meta tag data for social sharing purposes. This is my code which listens and render a html snapshot of the page I am trying to share:

```
var renderHtml = function(url, cb) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.loadImages = false;
    page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
    page.onCallback = function() {
        cb(page.content);
        page.close();
    };

page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.callPhantom();
        }, 10000);
    });
};
page.open(url);};

server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
var pageRoute = request.url;
var requestingUrl = renderedUrl+decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(pageRoute)).replace('/?_escaped_fragment_=/','/');
console.log(requestingUrl);

if(request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'facebookexternalhit/1.1'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'Facebot'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'Googlebot/2.1'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == '(+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
   || request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)'
   ||  request.headers["User-Agent"] == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)'
   ||(request.headers["User-Agent"]).indexOf('+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/') != -1){

    renderHtml(requestingUrl, function(html) {
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write(html);
        response.close();
    });  
}else{
    //redirect
}});
```

When I share the url of the prerender using [Google Share](https://plus.google.com/share?url=) it does not render the correct title and Description. It just shows the prerender link.

Comment: I use this library [Angular SEO](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo) and edited the angular-seo-server to the code above.

Comment: Here is answer for fb shareing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533846/single-page-application-with-angularjs-and-facebook-share-button